# Add a line break or similar when in a for loop and a value changes - jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have a db table with users and I am creating a hierarchy system.

Currently the top users (with a 1 hierarchy) are shown, and then when clicked I gather all the related users via ajax and display below.

These users have 4 or 5 tiers for their hierarchy. 1 being the highest level.

I want to be able to make a new line of users each time the hierarchy changes.

I query the db and fetch all the users with an order by of the hierarchy number, I then put them into an array, return with JSON and loop through in jQuery:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.userArray.length; i++){
  var user = data.userArray[i];
  $appendedItems.append(SHOW ALL USERS HERE);
}
```

Lets say the array is:

```
hierarchy => 2, 
hierarchy => 2, 
hierarchy => 2,
hierarchy => 3, 
hierarchy => 3, 
hierarchy => 4,
```

Each time the hierarchy changes, I would like to show a line break or something just to put the users on a new line to denote a lower level.

Thanks.

Comment: what people usually do is nest `ul`s inside `li`s and the list will be automatically padded with hierarchy

Comment: Have you tried adding a check for an increase in the hierarchy level?
Add a variable before the loop to store the current hierarchy, if the current iteration of the loop doesn't match (or is greater than) the hierarchy that is stored, indent (use line break or `ul > li > ul` etc).

Answer (score 0):

how I'd do it, obviously your case will be different but you can get the idea:

markup:

```
<ul id="#users">
    <li data-user-id="3">david</li>
    <li data-user-id="4">frank</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#users').on('click', 'li:not(.exploded)', function() {
    var $user = $(this).addClass('exploded'),
        userId = $user.data('userId'),
        url = '/getUsersChildres?user=' + userId;

    $.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
        $('<ul>', {
            html: $.map(data.userArray, function(i, user) {
                return $('<li>', {
                    text: user.name,
                    data: {
                        'userId': user.id
                    }
                });
            })
        }).appendTo($user);
    }, function() {
        $user.removeClass('exploded');
    });

    return false;
});
```

should end up with:

```
<ul id="#users">
    <li data-user-id="3" class="exploded">david
        <ul>
            <li data-user-id="13">jack</li>
            <li data-user-id="14">paul</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-user-id="4">frank</li>
</ul>
```